# Hide an html section when a shipping method is on the checkout page woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, shipping-method

I want to hide a certain html section when local pick option is available. I am not really familiar with coding but I have tried the following code. It does hide the section but checkout keeps spinning. Please could anyone help me with this? Thank you

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'unset_element', 9999, 2 );

function unset_element( $rates, $package ) {

if ( isset( $rates['flate_rate:8'] ) ) {

echo '<style>.dhl-delivery-services { display:none;} </style>';

}
return $rates;

}
```